# Better to insert at end of InnoDB primary key, or scattered throughout?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

What are the performance characteristics of inserting many small records from many clients into an InnoDB table, where the inserts all happen at the end of the primary key (e.g. with UUIDs where the leading digits are based on a timestamp) vs. scattered throughout the primary key (e.g. with UUIDs where the leading digits aren't based on a timestamp)? Is one preferable to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Appending keys to the end of an index is preferred because the index does not need to be reordered.

When inserting rows in the middle of the primary key index, since actual table data is stored on the same page as the primary keys in InnoDB, page data must be reordered (and relocated if a page fills up). MySQL does leave room for growth in each page, but some reordering and relocating is inevitable.

Page size in InnoDB is 16K, so if inserted rows are small, the effect is less.

Appending rows to the end of an index also requires less locks, though there may be more contention. Try to insert multiple rows in the same statement.

Appending also causes less fragmentation on disk, so sequential pages stay closer together. Disk fragmentation doesn't matter much, however, unless you are querying large amounts of sequential rows or performing table scanning instead of using indexes.

I wouldn't create an incremental surrogate primary key just so you can insert rows in order unless your number of writes (inserts) is higher than your reads (or perhaps because your rows are large and you are experiencing performance issues). If your reads are higher than your writes, being able to use a natural primary key may be a huge performance benefit.

Appending is more performant, but you should choose your method by considering all factors.